# Mapr sandbox connect to HBase from eclipse

Tags: hbase, sandbox, mapr

I have Mapr sandbox running in VMWare. How can I connect to the HBase running inside this VM from my Eclipse running on Windows? I keep getting the security error

> UG ClientCnxn:102 - zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false
>   2015-11-17 10:54:34 DEBUG ZooKeeperSaslClient:222 - JAAS loginContext
>   is: Client_simple 2015-11-17 10:54:34 INFO  Login:293 - successfully
>   logged in. 2015-11-17 10:54:34 INFO  ZooKeeperSaslClient:285 - Client
>   will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism. 2015-11-17 10:54:34 DEBUG
>   ZooKeeperSaslClient:287 - creating sasl client:
>   client=tpham104;service=zookeeper;serviceHostname=192.168.17.132
>   2015-11-17 10:54:39 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection
>   to server 192.168.17.132/192.168.17.132:5181. Will attempt to
>   SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client_simple'
>   2015-11-17 10:54:39 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection
>   established to 192.168.17.132/192.168.17.132:5181, initiating session
>   2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG ClientCnxn:892 - Session establishment
>   request sent on 192.168.17.132/192.168.17.132:5181 2015-11-17 10:54:39
>   INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server
>   192.168.17.132/192.168.17.132:5181, sessionid = 0x15114be8996001e, negotiated timeout = 40000 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG
>   ZooKeeperWatcher:430 - hconnection-0x2a1dd8a40x0,
>   quorum=192.168.17.132:5181, baseZNode=/hbase Received ZooKeeper Event,
>   type=None, state=SyncConnected, path=null 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG
>   ClientCnxnSocketNIO:184 - deferring non-priming packet:
>   clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 0,3 
>   replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response::  until
>   SASL authentication completes. 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG
>   ClientCnxnSocketNIO:184 - deferring non-priming packet:
>   clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 0,3 
>   replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response::  until
>   SASL authentication completes. 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG
>   ZooKeeperSaslClient:417 - ClientCnxn:sendSaslPacket:length=0
>   2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG ZooKeeperSaslClient:365 -
>   saslClient.evaluateChallenge(len=0) 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG
>   ZooKeeperWatcher:507 - hconnection-0x2a1dd8a4-0x15114be8996001e
>   connected 2015-11-17 10:54:39 ERROR ZooKeeperSaslClient:384 - An
>   error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by
>   GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
>   to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum
>   Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED
>   state. 2015-11-17 10:54:39 ERROR ClientCnxn:1015 - SASL authentication
>   with Zookeeper Quorum member failed:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error:
>   (java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by
>   GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
>   to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum
>   Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED
>   state. 2015-11-17 10:54:39 DEBUG ZooKeeperWatcher:430 -
>   hconnection-0x2a1dd8a4-0x15114be8996001e, quorum=192.168.17.132:5181,
>   baseZNode=/hbase Received ZooKeeper Event, type=None,
>   state=AuthFailed, path=null 2015-11-17 10:55:06 WARN  ZKUtil:483 -
>   hconnection-0x2a1dd8a4-0x15114be8996001e, quorum=192.168.17.132:5181,
>   baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /hbase/hbaseid   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>     at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:912)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(HConnectionManager.java:706)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:440)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:321)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:198)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:175)     at
>   com.optum.pafgen.service.HBaseService.main(HBaseService.java:58)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first set up the MapR client on Windows and then configure eclipse as explained here 
https://www.mapr.com/blog/basic-notes-on-configuring-eclipse-as-a-hadoop-development-environment-for-mapr
and here 
http://answers.mapr.com/questions/9903/hbase-client-for-windows.html

Comment: You're correct. However, I just couldn't get the Mapr client (Windows) to work. I keep getting error "No CLDB entries found...". Do you know how i can verify the CLDB ip:port information?